# How to link value/onChange in a component to a React hook with an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I have a component called Coord, which uses two SliderFields (see: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/components/sliderfield) to set the X and Y values of a coordinate (the default Y value is 50).

There are two Coords called Alice and Bob, and I'm passing in four useState hooks to keep track of the X and Y values for both coordinates.  What I want to do instead is keep all the coordinates in a list called coordList, also seen below.  How can I pass the coordList hook into the component to track the X and Y values of each coordinate, instead of using the other four hooks?

```
function App({ }) {
  const [coordAliceX, setCoordAliceX] = useState(0);
  const [coordAliceY, setCoordAliceY] = useState(50);
  const [coordBobX, setCoordBobX] = useState(0);
  const [coordBobY, setCoordBobY] = useState(50);

  // How to use this instead?
  const [coordList, setCoordList] = useState({
    Alice: { x:0, y:50 },
    Bob: { x:0, y:50 },
  });

  return (
    <View className="App">
      <Coord 
        coordName={'Alice'}
        xVal={coordAliceX} 
        yVal={coordAliceY} 
        onXChange={setCoordAliceX} 
        onYChange={setCoordAliceY} 
      /> 
      <Coord 
        coordName={'Bob'}
        xVal={coordBobX} 
        yVal={coordBobY} 
        onXChange={setCoordBobX} 
        onYChange={setCoordBobY} 
      /> 
    </View>
  );
}

function Coord({ coordName, xVal, yVal, onXChange, onYChange }) {
  return (
    <>
      <SliderField
        label="CoordX"
        name={"coordx"+coordName}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        value={xVal}
        onChange={onXChange}
      />
      <SliderField
        label="CoordY"
        name={"coordy"+coordName}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        value={yVal}
        onChange={onYChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: As a comment, I suggest you to get familiar with: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useReducer instead of having multiple `useState`'s trying to get grip of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App({}) {
  // const [coordAliceX, setCoordAliceX] = useState(0);
  // const [coordAliceY, setCoordAliceY] = useState(50);
  // const [coordBobX, setCoordBobX] = useState(0);
  // const [coordBobY, setCoordBobY] = useState(50);

  // How to use this instead?
  const [coordList, setCoordList] = useState({
    Alice: { x: 0, y: 50 },
    Bob: { x: 0, y: 50 }
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Coord
        coordName={"Alice"}
        xVal={coordList.Alice.x}
        yVal={coordList.Alice.y}
        setCoordList={setCoordList}
      />
      <Coord
        coordName={"Bob"}
        xVal={coordList.Bob.x}
        yVal={coordList.Bob.y}
        setCoordList={setCoordList}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function Coord({ coordName, xVal, yVal, setCoordList }) {
  return (
    <>
      <SliderField
        label="CoordX"
        name={"coordx" + coordName}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        value={xVal}
    // Here you need to some trick while updating and assigning
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCoordList((pre) => ({
            ...pre,
            [coordName]: { ...pre[coordName], x: e.target.value }
          }));
        }}
      />
      <SliderField
        label="CoordY"
        name={"coordy" + coordName}
        min={0}
        max={100}
        value={yVal}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCoordList((pre) => ({
            ...pre,
            [coordName]: { ...pre[coordName], y: e.target.value }
          }));
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: This can read the values correctly, but when it calls "setCoordList" the browser throws an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at App.js:232:1
    at basicStateReducer (react-dom.development.js:16540:1)`

"e.target.value" doesn't seem to be returning the right value.  This may have something to do with the SliderField component, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Isn't a   ```input```?..then what this ```SliderField``` ? How it's ```onChange``` behave?

Comment: SliderField is a component in AWS Amplify- here's the documentation: [link](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/components/sliderfield).  You can click "React source" on that page to view the source code.

I also tried changing the name of the slider to just "coordx" and changing the value to `e.target.coordx.value`, like the documentation, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Update: the value I needed was just `e` instead of `e.target.value`, otherwise your solution worked. Thanks!